# Ploting Multipoint with Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, plot

I created one geodataframe with geopandas. The geometry field was filled with Multipoint. However, when I try to plot the map to see multipoints, my map returned empty.

How can I plot geometry field (multipoint) using geopandas?

Here is a piece of it:

```
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

gs = GeoSeries([MultiPoint([(-120, 45), (121, 46)]), 
                MultiPoint([(-121.2, 46), (-123, 48)]), 
                MultiPoint([(-122.9, 47.5), (-125, 49)])])
print(gs)

gs.plot(marker='*', color='red', markersize=12, figsize=(4, 4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation suggests that the [plot_series()](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/plotting.py) function does not currently support MultiPoint geometries.

[image]

Would a single point geometry plot suffice for your purposes?

```
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Point

pnts = [(-120, 45), (-121, 46), (-121.2, 46), (-123, 48), (-122.9, 47.5), (-125, 49)]
gs = GeoSeries(Point(pnt[0],pnt[1]) for pnt in pnts)
ax = gs.plot(marker='*', color='red', markersize=12, figsize=(4, 4))
ax.set_xbound(-126, -119)
ax.set_ybound(44, 50)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Sincerely yours.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment yet, so posting a "answer".
With geopandas version 0.13.0 the OP's code works.  Shapely multipoint can now be plotted just fine.  This wasn't the case in 2017.

```py
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

gs = GeoSeries([MultiPoint([(-120, 45), (-121, 46)]), 
                MultiPoint([(-121.2, 46), (-123, 48)]), 
                MultiPoint([(-122.9, 47.5), (-125, 49)])])
print(gs)

gs.plot(marker='*', color='red', markersize=12, figsize=(4, 4))
```

**Note:** if you're trying to make this a geopandas dataframe instead of a geoseries pass the MultiPoints as a list to the GeoDataFrame geometry arg.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

geom = [MultiPoint([(-120, 45), (-121, 46)]), 
        MultiPoint([(-121.2, 46), (-123, 48)]), 
        MultiPoint([(-122.9, 47.5), (-125, 49)])]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=[1,2,3], columns = ["id"], geometry=geom)

# color by row
gdf.plot(column="id")
```